# Android PorterDuff masking with 9-patch is leaving a black square background in android 4.4

Tags: android, kotlin, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm trying to mask an ConstraintLayout with an 9-patch mask. In versions above Android 4.4 works normally. For Android 4.4 a black square appears on the screen like this: even with a different 9-patch.

[image]

This is the code where i mask with the 9-patch. The **backgroundMask** var is an **NinePatchDrawable**.

```
override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
    backgroundMask?.setBounds(0, 0, w, h)

    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
}

override fun dispatchDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas)

    backgroundMask?.let {
        it.paint.xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN)
        it.draw(canvas)
    }
}
```

I also set the `setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null)` and tried the `setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)` in the constructor of the view, but also not works for android 4.4.

Is there anything that I can use to fix this in this Android version ?

Comment: `PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OUT`?

Comment: Hii, thanks for the tryp. This will leave only an black square.

Comment: Have you set your `Paint` a color other than transparent? Also don't forget to set `setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)`

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found the issue. The issue was setting the `android:background` of the `ConstraintLayout` that we want to mask. For some reason this is not working in android 4. So to fix this i remove the `android:background` of the `ConstraintLayout` and applied a mask color to the view on `disPatchDraw()`, using the `canvas.drawColor(colorId)`, before the `super.onDispatchDraw()` was called.